# nginx docker file cannot open file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, openresty

I am writing to a create a docker file to run openresty nginx in a container.

my docker file is below.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest


ENV PATH="/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin:${PATH}"

LABEL info="running open resty on docker container"

RUN  apt-get update -y \
     && apt-get install -y wget \
     && wget -qO - https://openresty.org/package/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
     && apt-get -y install software-properties-common \
     && add-apt-repository -y "deb http://openresty.org/package/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" \
     && apt-get update -y \
     && apt-get install -y openresty
RUN mkdir -p /opt/poc

RUN cd /opt/poc \
       && mkdir logs \
       && touch logs/error.log \
       && mkdir conf \
       && cd ../

RUN chmod -R 755 /opt/poc 
WORKDIR /opt/poc


ADD ./conf/nginx.conf conf/

EXPOSE 8383


CMD ["nginx", "-p /opt/poc","-c conf/nginx.conf"]
```

The image gets built with no issues. But when I run the docker I am getting the below error message.

> nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "
>   /opt/poc/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
>   2017/09/23 03:35:44 [emerg] 1#1: open() " /opt/poc/ conf/nginx.conf"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory)

instead of running `CMD ["nginx", "-p /opt/poc","-c conf/nginx.conf"]` if I change to `CMD $ls` the docker is listing the conf and logs directory. so I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Don't invent the weel - use official docker image - https://hub.docker.com/r/openresty/openresty/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a tricky one, but I think I figured it out.

## TL;DR

Use this `CMD` (it has no spaces in `-p` and `-c` flags)

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;", "-p", "/opt/poc", "-c", "conf/nginx.conf"]
```

> The `-g daemon off;` flag brings nginx as a forward process. Otherwise, if this runs as a daemon, your container will just die after nginx started.

## Long Answer

The problem occurs when you add a spaced string to any of your `CMD` commands. In your case, `-p /opt/poc`, `-c conf/nginx.conf`.

I believe (and I would need to look more in docs/Docker source code to confirm) that [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) is ignoring one of the two "words" you put in your `CMD` parts.

As the documentation says, the recommended way is doing like this:

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]
```

So, in your case, your `params` are doing "more" than just being a param (the "more" is when you use a space there). So, removing the spacing and splitting the command to be in the way that docs say fixed the problem.

## Tip

I don't know what's your use case, but if you can, try to use the images provided by the community. In this example, the owners of `openresty` maintain the images:

https://hub.docker.com/r/openresty/openresty

Also, they provide a good documentation on how you can run it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for suggesting the demon off. I accepted your answer.